# Does Smartscreen allows your own applications to run?

Tags: smartscreen

My PC's Windows 10 Smartscreen does not block the assembly I built myself. However if I have someone else run it on their PC it is blocked right away.

Does it get a free pass because it is launched on the same PC it was built on?
If so, how can I test my application signing on my own PC?

Comment: I think I may have found the answer with this MSDN article regarding the Strong-Name Bypass Feature https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to download your application for the Smartscreen to kick in.

I emailed it to myself, downloaded it, and now I get the Smartscreen warning as well.